# VALUES clause in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to build a `Query` object in SQLAlchemy which will be the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 2, 3)) AS sq;
```

From what I see in the documentation, the `VALUES` clause appears only in use with `INSERT`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

well "VALUES" in an insert is the standard SQL, the standalone "VALUES" keyword is a Postgresql thing.  There's a quick compiler recipe for this one at [PGValues](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/PGValues) (copied here in case I change the wiki someday):

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FromClause
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column

class values(FromClause):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.list = args

    def _populate_column_collection(self):
        self._columns.update(
            [("column%d" % i, column("column%d" % i))
                    for i in xrange(1, len(self.list[0]) + 1)]
        )

@compiles(values)
def compile_values(element, compiler, asfrom=False, **kw):
    v = "VALUES %s" % ", ".join(
        "(%s)" % ", ".join(compiler.render_literal_value(elem, None) for elem in tup)
        for tup in element.list
    )
    if asfrom:
        v = "(%s)" % v
    return v

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = table('t1', column('a'), column('b'))
    t2 = values((1, 0.5), (2, -0.5)).alias('weights')
    print select([t1, t2]).select_from(t1.join(t2, t1.c.a==t2.c.column2))
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware that it's only postgresql that provides this use.

Comment: @zzzeek looks like `compiler.render_literal_value` now requires a type. What's the preferred way to determine it instead of hardcoding something like sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.STRINGTYPE?

Comment: Incidently, SQLServer since 2008 also supports this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx

Comment: @zzzeek Is this now supported without the recipe?

Comment: @plaes - It will be, once [this PR](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/pull/5030) is merged.

Answer (score 23):

This is now natively available in SQLAlchemy.

Your example would be written as:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.sql import Values

select(Values(column('Number', Integer), name='sq').data([(1,), (2,), (3,)]))
```

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this, but you can have a look at the test cases https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/test/sql/test_values.py

Comment: Does not work on sqlite though...

Comment: An alternative to values which is compatible with SQLite is `select(literal(val1).label("col1")).union_all(select(literal(val2)), select(literal(val3), ...).label("tablename")`.

Comment: Yes, UNION all is an option, but I would call it the poor man's VALUES alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func

select(['*']).select_from(func.values([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: This fails when I try to execute it `(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "("`

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but it worked for me:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

query = sa.select(['*']).select_from(sa.text("(VALUES (1,2,3)) as sq"))
connection.execute(query).fetchall()
```

`Output: [(1, 2, 3)]`

PS:
`VALUES` with the aliased columns example:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

query_cte = (
    sa.select([sa.column('age'), sa.column('name')])
        .select_from(sa.text("(VALUES (22, 'Bob'), (30, 'Julia')) as t (age, name)"))
).cte()
query_name = sa.select([query_cte.c.name])
connection.execute(query_name).fetchall()
```

`Output: [('Bob',), ('Julia',)]`

> WARNING: 
>   This solution is good for simple values. Be careful with the special 
>   symbols or words, they should be properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I went a bit further, to implement `SELECT INTO <table> VALUES (...)`.

The following implementation is designed to work with PostgreSQL and Python 3, and handles values of differing types (boolean, integer, float, JSON and varchar):

```
import json
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql import sqltypes, FromClause, Select

class SelectInto(Select):
    def __init__(self, columns, into, *arg, **kw):
        super(SelectInto, self).__init__(columns, *arg, **kw)
        self.into = into

@compiles(SelectInto)
def _select_into(element, compiler, **kw):
    text = compiler.visit_select(element, **kw)
    text = text.replace("FROM", f"INTO {element.into} \nFROM")
    return text

class Values(FromClause):
    text_type = sqltypes.UnicodeText

    def __init__(self, cols, types=None, *args):
        self.cols = cols
        self.vals = args

        if isinstance(self.cols, str):
            self.cols = [c.strip().join('""') for c in self.cols.split(",")]

        if not types:
            self.types = [self.text_type for _ in range(len(self.cols))]
        elif len(cols) == len(types):
            self.types = [self._map_col_type(t) for t in types]
        else:
            raise exc.ArgumentError("Types do not correspond to columns")

    def _map_col_type(self, col_type):
        if isinstance(col_type, sqltypes.TypeEngine):
            return col_type

        col_type = col_type.lower()

        if col_type in ("bool", "boolean"):
            return sqltypes.Boolean
        elif col_type in ("int", "integer", "number"):
            return sqltypes.Integer
        elif col_type in ("float", "double"):
            return sqltypes.Float
        elif col_type in ("json",):
            return postgresql.json.JSON
        elif col_type in ("jsonb",):
            return postgresql.json.JSONB

        return self.text_type

@compiles(Values)
def _compile_values(element, compiler, **kw):
    value_cols = ",".join(element.cols)
    value_sets = ", ".join(
        "({values})".format(
            values=",".join(_compile_value(compiler, val, element.types[idx]) for idx, val in enumerate(tup))
        )
        for tup in element.vals
    )
    return f'(VALUES {value_sets}) AS "values" ({value_cols})'

def _compile_value(compiler, value, type_):
    if value is None:
        return "NULL"
    elif issubclass(type_, sqltypes.JSON):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value = json.dumps(value)
        return f"'{value}'::{type_.__name__}"

    if issubclass(type_, sqltypes.String):
        value = str(value)

    return compiler.render_literal_value(value, type_())
```

To test this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression column

select_cols = [column(c) for c in 'one,two,three'.split(',')]
select_from = Values(['one', 'two', 'three'], ['varchar', 'int', 'bool'], *(('a',1,0),('aa',11,1),('aaa',111,0)))
select_into = SelectInto(select_cols, 'test_select').select_from(select_from)
print(select_into)
```

Comment: This functionality is now available in a postgres-specific project that wraps `sqlalchemy` and makes spatial indexing and advanced text search easy: https://github.com/consbio/pg-database-utils

Answer (score -3):

I'm not exactly sure but you can try the following options:

```
SELECT * FROM (select 1 as col1 union select 2 as col1 union select 3 as col1) AS sq
```

Comment: Sorry, not even close. The question is about doing the _described_ query in SQLAlchemy.