# python sqlalchemy built temporary table sub-select

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, temp-tables

I'm working on a very complex raw sql statement that has to be run with sqlalchemy. One part of the statement is a JOIN with a temporary table that is filled with data from a csv file.

The select is looking as follows:

```
(SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('1','xyz@something.com','+99123456798')) AS t (id, email, phone))
```

To prevent any sql injections I cannot simply copy paste everything from within the csv into the select.

I know that sqlalchemy has the option of inserting values with `:x` and then pass the actual value in the `execute` method, but I have A LOT of values and substituting them will be impossible.

Is there a way to build this temporary table from the csv with the necessary sql injection protection using sqlalchemy?

Comment: How about loading the rows in pandas and push rows from there?. Or read_csv row by row and convert them to `dict` which can be used for insertion and you need not care about the substitution. All you need to pass is a valid data structure.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858291/values-clause-in-sqlalchemy?