# sqlalchemy to create temporary table

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I created a temporary table with sqlalchemy (with an underlying postgres database) that is going to be joined with a database table. However, in some cases when a value is empty `''` then postgres throws the error:

```
failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
```

SqlAlchemy assembles everything to the following context

```
[SQL: 'WITH temp_table AS \n(SELECT %(param_1)s AS id, %(param_2)s AS email, %(param_3)s AS phone)\n SELECT campaigns_contact.id, campaigns_contact.email, campaigns_contact.phone \nFROM campaigns_contact JOIN temp_table ON temp_table.id = campaigns_contact.id AND temp_table.email = campaigns_contact.email AND temp_table.phone = campaigns_contact.phone'] [parameters: {'param_1': 83, 'param_2': '', 'param_3': '+1234567890'}]
```

I assemble the temporary table as follows

```
stmts = []
for row in import_data:
    row_values = [literal(row[value]).label(value) for value in values]
    stmts.append(select(row_values))

subquery = union_all(*stmts)
subquery = subquery.cte(name="temp_table")
```

The problem seems to be the part here

```
...%(param_2)s AS email...
```

which after replacing the `param_2` results in

```
...'' AS email...
```

which will cause the error mentioned above.
One way to solve the issue is to perform a cast

```
...''::text AS email...
```

However, I don't know how to perform `::text` cast with sqlalchemy!?

Comment: I am not entirely following your question  but I think you can do cast using `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast` in sqlalchemy queries

Comment: Btw since you're using Postgresql, you could use VALUES directly instead of UNION ALL. There's a recipe for that for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858291/values-clause-in-sqlalchemy