# VALUES clause in SQLAlchemy without column name (to be compatible with sqlite)

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have seen the answers from here [VALUES clause in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858291/values-clause-in-sqlalchemy) without being satisfactory. Basically SQLAlchemy forces you to give each column a name building the query as

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 2, 3)) AS sq (colname1, colname2);
```

instead of using the default names "column1, column2, ..." when you don't specify `(colname1, colname2)`. The problem with this is that specifying the column names is not compatible with sqlite. Do you know any way of doing that? I am thinking of using bare text query. The problem with that is that my full query is

```sql
SELECT pairs.column1 AS element_id,
    pairs.column2 as variant_id,
    products_elements.name as element_name,
    elements_variants.name as variant_name
FROM (
        VALUES (1, 2),
            (2, 2),
            (3, 1)
    ) AS pairs
    JOIN (products_elements, elements_variants) ON (
        products_elements.id = pairs.column1
        AND elements_variants.id = pairs.column2
    );
```

and I don't know how to embed the values. Thanks

Comment: For documentation purposes. You can insert values inside a sql text in sqlalchemy by using binding params. You do something like `FROM :pair_values` and then use `query.bindparams(sql.bindparam("pair_values", expanding=True, value=pairs))`. The `expanding=True` is crucial as it will expand `[(1, 1), (1, 1),...]` as `VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), ...`. You can even be more strict by specifying `type_=types.TupleType(types.Integer, types.Integer` inside `bindparam`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a raw query you can name to columns with a `CTE`:

```
WITH pairs(colname1, colname2) AS (VALUES (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1))
SELECT pairs.colname1 AS element_id,
       pairs.colname2 AS variant_id,
       products_elements.name AS element_name,
       elements_variants.name AS variant_name
FROM pairs
JOIN products_elements ON products_elements.id = pairs.colname1 
JOIN elements_variants ON elements_variants.id = pairs.colname2;
```